# Clicking on badge in achievements shows mobile web instead of badge profile page

Tags: bug, ios-app, achievements-dialog

I noticed a small bug when clicking on the badge in the achievements overview. Instead of taking you to the badge tab in your profile on the mobile web site or desktop web site, it shows the default page on the mobile web site:

[image]

Clicking on Copy Editor takes you here:

[image]

Expected to go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993547/patrick-hofman?tab=badges) for me.

Comment: Yup, should take you to the badges tab of your profile though, not the badge info page. (see in desktop site what happens when clicking the achievement)

Comment: Behavior on iPad is even weirder: it opens the SO main page inside the popup!